# Using sub queries to insert a value when a field is blank

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm trying to write a query that groups organisations by their abbreiviations instead of their code.  However, in some instances, the orgcode field will be blank.  This means I need to look at the customer postcode field and group accordingly based on that.  I have written the following query:

```
SELECT  
     dem.N1_1_NUMBER, 
     dem.N1_8_POSTCODE,
     src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN,
     Case
          When src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN IN ('XRT01', 'XRT02') Then 'ILR'
          When src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN IN ('XRTBP', 'XRTBU') Then 'HGF'
          When src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN =   'XRTBW'           Then 'HGW'
          When src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN IS NULL 
               Then (Select
                       Case
                         When LEFT(dem.N1_8_POSTCODE, 4) in ('LA1 ', 'LA2 ', 'LA3 ', 'LA4 ', 'LA5 ', 'LA6 ','LA7 ','LA8 ') Then 'RLI'
                         When LEFT(dem.N1_8_POSTCODE, 4) in ('LA9 ', 'LA10', 'LA11') Then 'WGH'
                         When LEFT(dem.N1_8_POSTCODE, 4) in ('LA12', 'LA13', 'LA14', 'LA15', 'LA16') Then 'FGH'
                         Else 'Unknown'
                      End

                     From Register.dbo.tblMAIN_REFERRALS mr

                          LEFT JOIN Register.dbo.tblDEMOGRAPHICS dem
                             ON mr.Customer_ID = dem.Customer_ID
                    ) End as [ORG SEEN]                                             

FROM    Register.dbo.MAIN_REFERRALS src

        Left JOIN Register.dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS dem
            ON src.PATIENTID = dem.PATIENTID
```

When I run the query, I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I'm not entirely sure why the query isn't working so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need that sub-query.. Try something like this

```
SELECT dem.N1_1_NUMBER,
       dem.N1_8_POSTCODE,
       src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN,
       CASE
         WHEN src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN IN ( 'XRT01', 'XRT02' ) THEN 'ILR'
         WHEN src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN IN ( 'XRTBP', 'XRTBU' ) THEN 'HGF'
         WHEN src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN = 'XRTBW' THEN 'HGW'
         WHEN src.N1_3_ORG_CODE_SEEN IS NULL THEN
           CASE
             WHEN LEFT(dem.N1_8_POSTCODE, 4) IN ( 'LA1 ', 'LA2 ', 'LA3 ', 'LA4 ',
                                                  'LA5 ', 'LA6 ', 'LA7 ', 'LA8 ' ) THEN 'RLI'
             WHEN LEFT(dem.N1_8_POSTCODE, 4) IN ( 'LA9 ', 'LA10', 'LA11' ) THEN 'WGH'
             WHEN LEFT(dem.N1_8_POSTCODE, 4) IN ( 'LA12', 'LA13', 'LA14', 'LA15', 'LA16' ) THEN 'FGH'
             ELSE 'Unknown'
           END
       END AS [ORG SEEN]
FROM   Register.dbo.MAIN_REFERRALS src
       LEFT JOIN Register.dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS dem
              ON src.PATIENTID = dem.PATIENTID
```

Comment: This works perfectly - I always seem to over complicate things!  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

This means your subquery to pull the postcode field is returning more than one row... the subquery is not referencing anything from your outer query, so it's returning everything.
Unless I'm missing something... instead of doing

```
                 From Register.dbo.tblMAIN_REFERRALS mr

                      LEFT JOIN Register.dbo.tblDEMOGRAPHICS dem
                         ON mr.Customer_ID = dem.Customer_ID
```

try

```
                 From Register.dbo.tblMAIN_REFERRALS mr
                  WHERE mr.Customer_ID = dem.Customer_ID
```

Doing that makes your subquery only return the results relevant for each row of the outer query.